# Labels in navigation bar, possible and "allowed"?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to add a label in the navigationbar? The purpose is to display a timer that is relevant to the game I'm porting. (What I want is the back button on the left and the timer and restart button on the right).

If possible, is it a good idea from a iOS point of view?

Thanks

AnkMannen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `UiViewController` has a `Title` property. This allows you to set the text within the top navigation bar. And yes, it is a good idea to use it!